# Adjust Text Box dimensions according to Rect when it is scaled

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I wanted the TextBox to adjust or fit exactly with the dimensions of rect on scaling the rect object in fabricjs

I'm calling the "calculateTextboxWidth" function on scaling the rect object to update the dimensions of the Textbox. In the function I'm using the rect translateX and translateY properties to get the new dimensions after scaling and then updating it to the TextBox Object width and height

I'm not able to find any solution even in the fabricjs docs

Demo: https://youtu.be/4WJYwQKJ7AU

Website: https://copper-oliy-51.tiiny.site/

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas')

fabric.RectWithText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
  type: 'rectWithText',
  text: null,
  textOffsetLeft: 0,
  textOffsetTop: 0,
  _prevObjectStacking: null,
  _prevAngle: 0,

  recalcTextPosition: function () {
    const sin = Math.sin(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle))
    const cos = Math.cos(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle))
    const newTop = sin * this.textOffsetLeft + cos * this.textOffsetTop
    const newLeft = cos * this.textOffsetLeft - sin * this.textOffsetTop
    const rectLeftTop = this.getPointByOrigin('left', 'top')
    this.text.set('left', rectLeftTop.x + newLeft)
    this.text.set('top', rectLeftTop.y + newTop)
  },


  calculateTextboxWidth: function (react) {
    const { translateX, translateY } = react;
    let width = translateX;
    let height = translateY;
    const setCords = { width, height } //translateY, translateX

    this.text.set(setCords);
    this.canvas.set('dirty', true);
    this.canvas.renderAll();
    console.log(react);
  },

  initialize: function (rectOptions, textOptions, text) {
    this.callSuper('initialize', rectOptions)
    this.text = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
      ...textOptions,
      selectable: false,
      evented: false,
    })
    this.textOffsetLeft = this.text.left - this.left
    this.textOffsetTop = this.text.top - this.top
    this.on('moving', () => {
      this.recalcTextPosition()
    })
    this.on('rotating', () => {
      this.text.rotate(this.text.angle + this.angle - this._prevAngle)
      this.recalcTextPosition()
      this._prevAngle = this.angle
    })
    this.on('scaling', (e) => {
      this.calculateTextboxWidth(e.target);
      this.recalcTextPosition()
    })
    this.on('added', () => {
      this.canvas.add(this.text)
    })
    this.on('removed', () => {
      this.canvas.remove(this.text)
    })
    this.on('mousedown:before', () => {
      this._prevObjectStacking = this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking
      this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true
    })
    this.on('mousedblclick', () => {
      this.text.selectable = true
      this.text.evented = true
      this.canvas.setActiveObject(this.text)
      this.text.enterEditing()
      this.selectable = false
    })
    this.on('deselected', () => {
      this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking = this._prevObjectStacking
    })
    this.text.on('editing:exited', () => {
      this.text.selectable = false
      this.text.evented = false
      this.selectable = true
    })
  }
})

const rectOptions = {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 200,
  height: 75,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFA5',
}
const textOptions = {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 200,
  height: 75,
  fontSize: 20,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFA9',
}
const rectWithText = new fabric.RectWithText(rectOptions, textOptions, 'Some text')
canvas.add(rectWithText)
```

Comment: 1) I don't think there's translateX or translateY on the object that you're trying to read them from. 2) even if they were there, translate X/Y refer to the X/Y position of things, not their dimensions; you might've been thinking of scaleX/Y

Comment: Dear @shkaper, I have updated my question with a video. Please watch the video and guide me if there is another way or approach of doing it that matches my requirement in fabricjs. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, using translateX/Y doesn't make sense in this context. Look at scaleX/scaleY of the rectangle instead, and change the width/height of your text accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @shkaper, I'm able to adjust using scaleX*width properties to get the new value. Previously I was doing it wrong using translateX/Y properties. Thanks a lot!!.